# Identifying Collapse in Wave-function

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, wavefunction-collapse, quantum-measurements

Is there a machine or instrument which will notify us instantly when the wave-function has collapsed if we have access to only one of the entangled particles? Note that the wave function collapse will be triggered by observing the particle which we do not have. Or in other words is there a way to identify (instantaneously) if the entangled pair of a particle has been *observed* and the wave function has collapsed.

Comment: Don't ask twice (almost) the same question, but update your original one if necessary. [Collapse in Wave-function](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/572774/collapse-in-wave-function)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know :). I'm new here so don't know how it works.